# Javascript interferring with GTM

Tags: javascript, events, download, accordion, google-tag-manager

I've discovered that an accordion script is interfering with GTM set to track PDF downloads. The accordion script opens and collapses a list of download links. It's actually 2 scripts; the first initiates ddaccordion.js and the 2nd sets the parameters.

They were in the head and then I tried them at the end of the page - no difference. If I remove one or the other script, GTM begins tracking downloads. All other PDF downloads track normally throughout the site.

These are the 2 scripts:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddaccordion.js">

    /*••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
    • Accordion Content script- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
    • Visit http://www.dynamicDrive.com for hundreds of DHTML scripts
    • This notice must stay intact for legal use
    ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••*/

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        ddaccordion.init({
                headerclass: "expandable", //Shared CSS class name of headers group that are expandable
                contentclass: "categoryitems", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
                revealtype: "click", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
                mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
                collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false 
                defaultexpanded: [], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc]. [] denotes no content
                onemustopen: false, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
                animatedefault: true, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
                persiststate: false, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
                toggleclass: ["", "openheader"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
                togglehtml: ["prefix", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
                animatespeed: "2500", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
                oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initalized
                    //do nothing
                },
                onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){ //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
                document.getElementById('main-content').style.height=document.getElementById('side-bar').style.height=document.getElementById('photo-bar').style.height=document.getElementById('anchor').offsetTop+'px';;

                //do nothing   "side-bar", "main-content", "photo-bar"
                }
            })


    </script>
```

Is there a way to fix this without losing the accordion function?

Comment: In the "ddaccordion.js" file look for occurences of "return false" and replace them with e.preventDefault(). As GTM will not work when the default behavior of the clicked element is cancelled with "return false" this might be worth a shot (educated guess, not tested, so a comment rather than an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace "return false" in the ddaccordion.js script (which occurred once) with "e.preventDefault()". Thanks to @Eike-Pierstorff for the solution.